# Form Calculation. Is there an easier way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am creating a sort of order portal for work and have worked out everything i need to do so far (mostly from information from here. thank you all!).

The only thing I don't like the idea of is copying and pasting the calculation javascript and editing the name/id for each calculation.

Is there a way to do it quicker than copying and pasting the calculation script and then editing each element? I have to create this for another couple of forms which will take an age if i have to do it this way!

As you will hopefully see in my test page, the price is pulled from the html, the qty is pulled from the input and the calculation is output to the Total price column.

Please bear in mind i don't have any javascript knowledge aside from copying code and change it so a little explaining may be needed.

Page i am referring to is http://www.catering-equipment.co.uk/portal1/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: edit: the finished one looks like this one from JotForm which is already set up, but the JotForm platform doesn't do everything I want it to (export to a self formatted PDF, save to own server) http://catering-equipment.co.uk/portal1/test.html

Comment: What you're asking is unclear, can briefly explain what you're trying to copy paste?

Comment: sorry, copying and pasting the javascript for calculating the total at the end of each row

$("#vmbu").on('keyup',function(){
   // alert('pressed')
        var vmbucalc = $("#vmbu_price").html() * $(this).val() 
    $("#vmbucalc").val(vmbucalc);
})

Comment: Seeing your HTML + JS would improve your question a lot, and save you from being downvoted. Without those, all I can suggest is that you Google the 'DRY principle'

Comment: have now added, completely forgot

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is put the calculation in a separate javascript file, then  **include** it in each page to put the same calculation in every page.

Remember that the calculation referring to the elements should be done after the form and its elements are defined, so putting the include under the form or possibly at the very end before the `</body>` closure tag would be best. It's basically like adding in a `.js` file from a plug-in, ideally you should put all javascripts in a subfolder together.

Example include:

```
<script src="javascripts/calculate.js"></script>
```